# MySQL #2006 server has gone away/Connection for controluser as defined in your configuration failed. PHP 7.0.4 and MySQL 5.7.12

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I had phpMyAdmin installed on Ubuntu 15.10 with PHP 5.6.11 and MySQL 5.6.30, and everything worked fine.

I upgraded to Ubuntu 16.04 which installed PHP 7.0.4 and MySQL 5.7.12. Now when I attempt to log in to phpMyAdmin, I get

```
#2006 - MySQL server has gone away
```

and

```
Connection for controluser as defined in your configuration failed.
```

I have verified through both command line mysql and via mysqli_connect in a php script that I can access the phpmyadmin mysql database as the controluser with the controlpass. The web server runs this php with no problem

```
<?php
$mysqli = mysqli_connect("localhost", "controluser", "controlpass", "phpmyadmin");
if (mysqli_connect_errno($mysqli)) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
$res = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * from pma_recent");
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)):
var_dump($row);
echo "<br><br>";
endwhile;
?>
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

With the upgrade to PHP 7.0.4 and MySQL 5.7.12, the following configuration needed:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['ssl'] = false;
```

Comment: Actually, that's the default. The issue is that I had

Comment: Actually, that's the default. The issue is I had `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['ssl'] = true;` without the other settings for certificates and keys, and this had worked prior to the upgrade, but not after, so the solution was to change it to `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['ssl'] = false;` or just removing it would work to.